# How to force mysqldump to produce /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, collation, character-set

I am attempting to dump my database, which is set to, and only contains, `utf8mb4` and appropriate collations. I use the following line:

`mysqldump --add-drop-table --add-locks --allow-keywords --complete-insert=TRUE --compress --create-options --databases [database] --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --disable-keys --dump-date --extended-insert=FALSE --hex-blob --lock-tables=FALSE --no-autocommit --no-data --set-charset --order-by-primary --quote-names --routines --single-transaction --skip-quick --triggers -u [user] -h [server] > dump.sql`

This works well and produces the output I want, with one exception. My dump is littered with this:

```
/*!40101 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results = utf8 */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */;
```

I have read up on conditional comments, and as I understand it, this will always get executed on our clients/servers (Server Version: 5.6.46 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)). I don't understand why this is set to `utf8` instead of `utf8mb4`, and would like it to reflect our proper charset.

None of the existing answers to this problem have helped me.

Edit: I originally had an incorrect version in my post

Comment: Which mysql version, exactly, are you using?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Comment: @RickJames as far as I know you can't supply your own SQL to `mysqldump`. Running `mysql` with similar parameters results in `character_set_client = utf8mb4, character_set_connection = utf8mb4, character_set_database = utf8mb4, character_set_filesystem = binary, character_set_results = utf8mb4, character_set_server = latin1, character_set_system = utf8`, all of which seems correct. As @Isotopp pointed out, the problem seems to be in the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have checked out mysql-5.4.46, and searched client/mysqldump.c for "SET character_set_client".

It finds

```
[:~/Source/mysql-server/client]↥ 9c3a49ec84b* ± grep 'SET character_set_client' mysqldump.c
          "/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = %s */ %s\n"
          "/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ %s\n"
                  "SET character_set_client = utf8;\n"
                  "SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;\n");
                "/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;\n"
                "/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;\n",
            "/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = %s */;\n"
            "/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;\n"
```

From this, it seems that some instances of "SET character_set_client" are fixed at utf8 in this version and are not even variable.

One of them is the `/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;` line you quote as being faulty.

After checking out current 8.0 HEAD, I get

```
[:~/Source/mysql-server/client]↥ 8.0* ± grep 'SET character_set_client' mysqldump.cc
          "/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = %s */ %s\n"
          "/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ %s\n"
                  "/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;\n"
                  "SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;\n");
              "/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;\n"
              "/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;\n",
        "/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = %s */;\n"
        "/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;\n"
```

So while there are still fixed `SET character_set_client` statements, they now default to utf8mb4. Note that all other statements are %s-ed, and further checking shows they defer to whatever you `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` in your commandline.

My suggestion is you dump, possibly remotely, with a newer mysql 8.0 binary. In general, upgrading is adviseable, as 5.6 is an outdated unsupported version of the database (yes, I know, it's complicated. It always is.)

Comment: Thank you for looking that up. From that answer I gather that there is no solution to the problem with our current setup. I will investigate whether we can upgrade our `mysqldump` version(s).

Comment: (perhaps you meant 5.6.46?)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there has been a bug on the issue:

----- 2019-07-22 8.0.17 General Availability -- -- -----

mysqldump failed to wrap SET NAMES utf8mb4 and SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 statements within version-specific comments, which could cause compatibility problems. (Bug #29007506, [Bug #93450](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93450))

----- 2018-11-20 MariaDB 10.3.11 -- Release Note -- -----

[mysqldump](/kb/en/mysqldump/) now uses utf8mb4 as a default [character set](/kb/en/character-sets/), instead of utf8.